# Механизм работы регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На большинстве ресурсов где я побывал информация по поводу регулярных выражений излагается в таком виде: "вот эти символы для того то а эти для того то. Если напишем так то, то найдутся такие совпадения". Меня интересуют следующие вопросы

1. Какие процессы происходят между тем моментом как я написал регулярку и до того момента, как какой то механизм каким то образом находит подходящие строки и выдает результат?
2. Смысл использовать всякие алгоритмы поиска строк типа Ахо Корася и БМХ если есть регулярки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала рекомендую прочитать книгу [Джеффри Фридла «Регулярные выражения»](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4066500/). Она приоткроет немного занавес тайны.

теперь по вопросам.

1. Самое первое - регулярка парсится и преобразуется в более удобный для движка вид (иногда это называют компиляцией). Некоторые движки делают "граф" для машины состояний, некоторые делают сразу "байт код". [пример на хабре](https://habr.com/post/166777/). А потом по этому графу или "коду" проходятся и проверяют совпадение.
2. Да, иногда имеет смысл. Если регулярка применяется разок-другой, то смысла в дополнительных алгоритмах нет. А если регулярка выполняется в нагруженном цикле, то алгоритмы поиска подстрок имеют смысл. Мой опыт показывает, что переписывание регулярок "один-к-одному" с перла на с++ (Qt), дает двукратное падение скорости обработки (программа - построчный парсинг большого (десятки мегабайт) текстового файла). Добавление пары if с проверкой на подстроку для отсеивания заведомо неверных вариантов выровняло скорость.